# Debian 8 not visible on network

Tags: debian, network-interface

I have a debian server connected to 1 Wi-Fi access point. Other devices at the same access point cannot FTP, SSH, and connect to apache webserver. The other devices cannot even ping Debian's IP. All the errors show something like **Connection Refused**. Ifconfig shows:

```
wlan0   
          Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
          inet addr:10.0.0.8  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a00:1028:9194:d146:5ab0:35ff:fe88:699a/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::5ab0:35ff:fe88:699a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3593 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:5179
          TX packets:3867 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1598742 (1.5 MiB)  TX bytes:564225 (551.0 KiB)
          Interrupt:21
```

I don't believe the problem being IP interference, as even changing the inet addr several times does not solve the problem. I did no change to **NetworkManager.conf** or **/etc/interfaces**

iwconfig shows:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Internet_kids"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: 6A:F4:AB:02:2B:70   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Output of netstat can be found here:http://pastebin.com/rKT6u19r

I do not use iptables. Instead, I use ufw, and the rules are:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
21                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8079                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8079                       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Output of `route` is:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: It seems to be working. Could you show the ouput of iwconfig, iptables -Ln, ps aux and netstat -an?

Comment: Can you access services from the Debian server?  That is, can you ping other devices etc? If that works, check your firewall.

Comment: Please refer to https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse . Also as a side note : the config file you're referring to is /etc/network/interfaces . Also, paste the output of `route` . Ta.

Comment: I just remembering an interesting tidbit. Which wifi are you talking about? At home? We run the wireless services at the faculty, and there is an option there to forbid conversations between AP clients.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro This is a home Wi-Fi. Most probably configured without special settings. I am not the administrator at the home Wi-Fi either. Interestingly, I can only see 1 or 2 devices connected, mainly the Ethernet cable ones

Comment: can Debian ping other IPs?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It can't. `arp -a` shows `10.0.0.5` which is my OS X laptop IP, but the ping shows `Host unreachable`

Comment: Please show us the output of "sudo ufw status verbose"

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro `status` and `status verbose` show the same output, which is in the question

Comment: What happens if you run sudo ufw disable? Are you able to see it?

Comment: hmmm you have a public IPv6 address and IPv6 takes precedence over IPv6...that may explain some problems, however does not explain why you are not able to see and ping the IPv4 address.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro `ufw disable` does not fix the ping to other device or to debian. Shouldn't we continue troubleshooting in chat room?

Comment: I have to leave for lunch, and actually out of ideas currently. One step I would try is to disable IPv6, although I do not think it is the source of the problem.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I think the problem could be in router config, but I can't fix that until later in this week

Comment: Since you are getting IPv4 and public IPv6 addresses, it does not seem to be a connectivity issue.

Comment: That `HWaddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` may cause communication problems. What model is your WiFi interface, and what kernel version are you running?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/67064/unable-to-connect-to-wired-dhcp-connection-via-my-pc for more explanation and possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that on the **WPA2** secured Wi-Fi network, there is client isolation enabled. My solution was to port-forward the server to public ip, and access it that way, or make an ARP entry

```
arp -s 10.0.0.8 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Running this command on other devices allowed me to connect